# Rename files using shell with occurence more than once

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to rename files like *%3A*%3A*.xml to *:*:*.xml.

```
MODFILE=`echo $1 | tr -s '"%3A"' ':'`
mv $1 "${MODFILE}"
```

Does the Job as long as i dont have %3A more than once directly consecutive. I searched a lot and found several Scripts to rename just the first occurrence or its only working when i only have one occurrence.

For example this works only with one occurrence:

```
for files in *%3A*.xml
do
  mv "$files" "${files/%3A/:}"
done
```

Can someone please help me with this? I'm not that comfortable with shellscripting :/

Comment: Your `tr` script is incorrect; it will replace sequences of `"` or `%` or `3` or `A` with a single colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, if you use:

```
mv "$files" "${files//%3A/:}"
```

(two slashes instead of one), then all occurrences will be replaced.

Comment: Wow this was so easy o.O i dont get it why are the people all posting such complicated Scripts xD? And why is it working with // but not /?

Comment: Bash replace syntax: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html (see substring replacement)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to use rename

```
 rename %3A : *
```

It may take only the first occurence, but then you have to execute it again.

Rename may also accept the regular expression as input, but that depends on the system.

Comment: yes it only takes the first one and then i have to execute it 10 times which is not that great...

Comment: @DennisIch Then you should test for your system rename accepts regular expression, then rename `'s/%3A/:/g' *` or something like that may work